# Dart deployment query - how to deploy a dart code on server + configuration management

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Please help me to some pointers on - how to deploy a dart code on server. 
Is it possible to deploy my dart code to Tomcat, JBoss servers? What configuration settings we have to do here?

From code configuration point of view, how my code should be bundled and deployed on server..

Is there any specific deployment tool or server best suited for Dart...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pub build` generates a directory `build` within your package containing the complete deliverable.
The files generated from 'pub build' can be used like any static content.